# Time loop paradox in The Flash

Tags: dc, time-travel, arrowverse, the-flash-2014, the-flash

In season 1, episode 15 (Out of Time), we see a time loop in the end.
Assuming the timeline when the episode started to be `x`, in the end, we get to timeline `x+1`.

So, does Barry retain his consciousness of timeline `x` when in timeline `x+1`? If yes, then did Barry of timeline `x` have the memories of timeline `x-1` when he saw a **speed mirage**? If so, why didn't he stop the events of timeline `x` from happening?

Comment: I have made no sense of the scene either, but my guess is that there are now 2 Barrys, the one from before, who will eventually try to stop the wave, and the second Barry who was just transported back in time. So the speed mirage never was a speed mirage but rather a second Flash.

Comment: But I saw them merge! They really did! The creators *will* have to explain this!

Comment: @Ranveer So did I, they _did_ merge, which is most likely why this time Barry sticks around a bit longer on his way to the morgue, and says "Oh Boy!". Now he maybe will stop the events from timeline x - sadly he _doesn't_ know what he *really* has to stop, since Caitlin didn't even know everything and what little she did, he cut her off before she could tell him.

Comment: [S1S18 SPOILERS] About time paradoxes, following the latest episode, why does Cisco remember being murdered

Comment: what do you consider to be timeline x-1 ? The original timeline where Barry's mother wasn't murdered?

Comment: Hadn't realized the -/+. I think it may be a typo. It's likely the timeline before Thawne traveled back and replaced Wells.

Answer (score 1):

> So, does Barry retain his consciousness of timeline x when in timeline x+1?

Yes. This is shown in the following episode where Barry tries to speak to Dr Wells about what he knows and remembers from Timeline X. The things he remembers includes all of the events with the Weather Wizard, the attacks on Joe and the police station/chief, the kidnapping of Iris, the tidal wave, and Iris' confession of feelings for him

> If yes, then did Barry of timeline x have the memories of timeline x-1 when he saw a speed mirage?

I'm going to assume that Timeline X-1 is the one where Nora Allen wasn't killed in the battle between Flashes, and Thawne didn't replace Dr. Wells.

In this case, the Barry(X) we see would not have full memories of Timeline X-1, as he never experienced those events himself.

> If so, why didn't he stop the events of timeline x from happening?

Barry *does* stop the events of Timeline X from happening - that's essentially what *creates* Timeline X-1. The differences between them all stem from Barry suddenly knowing what originally happened, and then taking actions to prevent them. Unfortunately, things did not end up how Barry expected/hoped (particularly in the case of Iris, and yet *another* person learning the true identity of The Flash),

Comment: nitpick: Captain Cold didn't show up in Timeline X, it was Weather Wizard.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Ah, right. Thanks. Too many weathermen.

Answer (score 0):

I believe he has the memories of x and x+1 at the end of the episode. The speed mirage seems like a glimpse of broken timeline. I do not believe he would have the memories of timeline x-1 though I can see the theory of two Barrys being correct. Maybe he caught a glimpse of himself coming back in time because he was moving close to the same speed just not quite there yet. My questions stem from everything Doctor Wells said to Cisco. The anti flash could move faster than the Flash so far so why is Barry's speed the key? How is he trapped in this present time. What did he mean when he told Cisco you have been dead to me for centuries?

Comment: Are you trying to ask a new question? If so, please click the "Ask Question" button in the upper right and post your question there.

Answer (score -3):

Ok, so I actually took a college class on time travel (cause my college was cool like that) and here's a synopsis of the answer in layman physics: 
Barry does merge because 2 of the same person can not exist in the same time line abut he did not yet have the memories at the merge because the Barry at that time had not experienced them yet. But he retained the memories after completing the run because at that point he had experienced them. Essentially they merge but still remain 2 separate Barry's. 
Thinking about time loops and paradoxes is probably the quickest way to get a migraine known to man.

Comment: The rules of time travel differ from one work to the next, and they have not been definitively established in the Flash/Arrow universe.